# Removing NANS Column WISE and Joining WITH Original Dataframe

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pivot, nan

I have a pandas data frame with 1000 of columns which I got from a sql pivot.
Out of that some columns have a substring
( like contains ALPHA ). Now what the dataframe looks like is this:  ( showing sample here
say for 5 ALPHA Columns).

The charecterstic of the data is that for each unoique combination of Cols A to ColE
there is at the most one non-null value for each  alpha column

```
      input_df 
      
        ColA   ColB   ColC   ColD  ColE    ALPHA_1   ALPHA_2  ALPHA_3  ALPHA_4   ALPHA_5.......
        
          x      y      z     p     q       NAN       1        NAN      NAN       2
          
          x      y      z     p     q        2        NAN      NAN       NAN      NAN

          x      y      z     p     q        NAN      NAN      11       NAN       NAN
          
          x      y      z     p     q        NAN      NAN      NAN       15        NAN
          
          u      v      w     z     k        11      NAN       NAN      NAN        1
          
          u      v      w     z     k       NAN      NAN       34       NAN        NAN
          
          u      v      w     z     k        NAN      6       NAN      NAN        NAN
          
          u      v      w     z     k       NAN      NAN       NAN       76        NAN
          
          b      d      y     s     t        NAN       4        NAN      NAN      NAN
          
          b      d      y     s     t        NAN       NAN      8         NAN      80
          
          b      d      y     s     t        NAN       NAN      NAN       9        NAN
          
          b      d      y     s     t        88        NAN      NAN        NAN    NAN
```

What I am looking for is to drop all NANS from Columns and combine & club them when the Cols A-E are same.
So the data should look like

```
        output_df  
        
        
         ColA   ColB   ColC   ColD  ColE    ALPHA_1  ALPHA_2  ALPHA_3  ALPHA_4    ALPHA_5 .......
        
        
          x      y      z     p     q       2       1        11        15         2
          
          u      v      w     z     k        11      6       34        76        1
          
          u      v      w     z     k       NAN      NAN       34       NAN        NAN
          
          u      v      w     z     k        NAN      6       NAN      NAN        NAN
          
          u      v      w     z     k       NAN      NAN       NAN       76        3
          
          b      d      y     s     t        88       4        8          9        8
```

What I planned is to create a subset of Cols from ColA to Col E and one
by creating a subset of cols containing only alpha and then drop the duplicates from the first dataframe(keydf)
and then drop the NANS from each of the columns from second dataframe (newdf) and then join the two dataframes by index.

```
          keydf = input_df.loc[:, input_df.columns.str.contains('COL')]
          
          newdf = input_df.loc[:, input_df.columns.str.contains('ALPHA')]
```

However, I am stuck at  this stage and not sure how to proceed. Any help will be immensely appreciated.

Comment: If you're confident that for every unique combination of `ColX` columns there is at most 1 value for each of the `ALPHA_X` columns, then I think you can just group on the `ColX` columns and apply `pd.Dataframe.sum` with `axis = 0`

Comment: some details pleae if you dont mind ( assuming only ColA & Col B) say. I think thts the case, but I can cofirm. Thanks

Comment: `input_df.groupby(["ColA", "ColB", "ColC", "ColD", "ColE"]).apply(pd.DataFrame.sum, axis=0).reset_index()`  give that a go, I haven't tested it because I'd need to reconstruct your dataframe from scratch.  If that doesn't work (may depend on version of pandas then try `input_df.groupby(["ColA", "ColB", "ColC", "ColD", "ColE"]).apply(lambda df: df[["ALPHA_1", "ALPHA_2", "ALPHA_3", "ALPHA_4", "ALPHA_5"]].sum(axis=0)).reset_index()`

Comment: thank you let me try and will keep you posted

Comment: Well the first did not work, for the second one, its not a good solution as then I have to manually specify all the 100's of alpha columns

Comment: I treid the second one two, but its giving two new columns as level 9 with the Alpha names unpivoted and a 0 column with those values. So this one is also not working.